# how to create a link of a certain type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

please help solve the problem.

have a controller:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@news = News.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    @news = News.page(params[:page])
  end

  def show

  end  
end
```

I'm trying to create a link like:

```
<%= link_to 'More', controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id %>
```

But multiline. To do this, create the following template:

```
<% @news.each do |news_item| %>
    <%= link_to(news_path, { controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id }) do %>
        <span>qwerty</span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The result is the following error message:

```
NameError in News#index
Showing /home/kalinin/rails/visit/app/views/news/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `news_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f221c8a0738>:0x007f221c391dc8>
```

rake routes:

```
..............
.........
       news_index GET    /news/index(.:format)           news#index
        news_show GET    /news/show(.:format)            news#show

............
..........
```

Comment: Paste the `rake routes` of news controller

Comment: news_show GET    /news/show(.:format)            news#show

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:-

```
<% @news.each do |news_item| %>
 <%= link_to "Qwerty", news_show_path(id: news_item.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you wanted to make this even more "Rails-y", you don't need to specify `id`, but rather you can just pass in the object itself: `link_to "Qwerty", news_show_path(news_item)`

Answer (score 0):

Use rake routes and check news_path route exist.also the first parameter of a link_to function should be name of link.

Comment: news_show GET    /news/show(.:format)            news#show

Comment: Then use news_show_path.and also use it in second parameter, you do not need to pass controller and action sepratly.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a read of the Rails Guides on routing.
I think you've got a conceptual misunderstanding that a quick read might help.

Start here :)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code

Answer (score -1):

```
<% @news.each do |news_item| %>
    <%= link_to(url_for({controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id})) do %>
      <div>
        <span>title:</span>
        <span><%= news_item.title %></span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>Date:</span>
        <span><%= news_item.created_at.to_s(:ru_datetime_for_news) %></span>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'More', controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id %>

    <br>
    <br>
      <br>
<% end %>
```